# How to loop after a loop statement is completed?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while

```
int guess_number = (gen() % 1000);
cout << guess_number;

int number = 0;
cout << "Number:";
cin >> number;

do
{
    if (number>guess_number)
    {
        cout << "Too High"<<"\n";
        cin >> number;
    }
    else if (number<guess_number)
    {
        cout << "Too Low"<< "\n";
        cin >> number;
    }
} while (number != guess_number);
  int again=0;  
  cout << "Wanna Play Again!";
  cin >> again;
```

I'm making a guessing game, but must loop the game if the player answers 1 after "Wanna Play Again!" I'am working with if,for,do, switch, and while statements. Its an assignment I was given and I just can't seem to figure out exactly how to loop the entier statement. I have made several attempts, but it either exits the program or continually prints "Wanna Play Again!".

Comment: Try two loops. `while (playing) { do { ask_number } while(bad_number); play_again }`

Comment: You can put that loop in a function and call that function.

Comment: My instructor would dock me if I put that in a function even though it is a rather quick and painless idea. As for the two loops I have attempted that to find that it keeps repeating "Wanna Play Again" over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping the existing do/while with a another for the play again condition ?

```
int again =0;
do{ 
  do{
     //existing code
  } //end inner while
  cout << "Wanna Play Again?";
  cin >> again;
} while(again != 0); //or whatever makes sense for the condition
```

Comment: Unfortunately it failed to work. It was a great try though the problem that occured was that it keep repeating the printed message "Wanna Play Again". I attempted a similar thing using a do and if statement awhile ago, but came up with no solution.

Comment: I just figured it out. So it looks like if I placed the do{ statement earlier in my code right before my number random generator command it works perfectly. Thanks to everyone helping!